# how to change DPI of an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Here is the problem to change an image resolution from 300 dpi to 200 dpi or 600 dpi. 
i am using matlab but how can i be. so for i have use the imresize function which down sample the image and up sample it.

```
 imresize(image, scale ,interpolation).
```

how can down sample the image to reduce its quality too. so that i may check the difference between the original image and the down sampled image.

```
j= imresize(I,0.2,'nearest');
```

where I is the original image and j is the down sampled image. is this changing the dpi of an image.

Answer (score 2):

[Dots per inch (DPI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) has **nothing** to do with the type of resizing done by `imresize`.  In fact, changing the DPI does not even require changing the actual image data, [just the metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch#DPI_or_PPI_in_digital_image_files) -- a property or label.  DPI gives you the information needed to go from pixels -> inches (print size).