# Matlab saving picture

Tags: matlab

I want to save a picture using this code, but when using the code to save a picture the size of the picture will be different with manual Save As.

Is there another method to save which is the same as the manual Save As method using code?

I had a try with this code (the data name: ffout2):

```
imagesc(fftout2); figure(gcf);
saveas(gcf,[pwdpath '\Image\' ClassName '\',WavClass(WavClassIndex).name '.jpg'], 'jpg');
```

or with:

```
print -djpeg 'FIG1.jpg';
```

Both codes export file all in 1201 x 901 , 24 bit (colour)

But using manual **Save As**, the size will be 561 x 420 , 24 bit (colour)

Comment: It is best to use `fullfile` command to define file names and paths instead of `[pwdPath '\Image' ...`. `fullfile` is OS onsensitve and makes it easier to port code across platforms.

Answer (score 4):

Your code

```
imagesc(fftout2);
figure(gcf);
saveas(gcf,[pwdpath '\Image\' ClassName '\',WavClass(WavClassIndex).name '.jpg'], 'jpg');
```

or

```
print -djpeg 'FIG1.jpg';
```

save MATLAB figure as it is presented on your screen with axes, tick labels, titles, etc.

But this code

```
imwrite(fftout2,'File.jpg');
```

writes pure image data to file.
Both ways are correct, depending oon what is your goal.

**EDIT1**

After the answer by @chappjc and his comment, I did some tests and it seems that all these ways may be tuned to provide the same image size even the `print` function with proper DPI settings. Check this code

```
img = rand(100,200,3);
figure;                                         % size is 560 x 420 pixels
imagesc(img);
get(gcf,'Position')
F = getframe(gcf);
size(F.cdata)
[im,map] = frame2im(F);
if isempty(map)
    imwrite(im,'SaveAsFig_RGB.png');            %  560 x  420 image
else
    imwrite(im,map,'SaveAsFig_WithCMAP.png');   %  
end
print(gcf, '-djpeg',       'FIG_000.jpg');      % 1200 x  900 image
print(gcf, '-djpeg','-r70','FIG_070.jpg');      %  560 x  420 image
print(gcf, '-djpeg','-r72','FIG_072.jpg');      %  576 x  432 image
print(gcf, '-djpeg','-r96','FIG_096.jpg');      %  768 x  576 image
get(0,'ScreenPixelsPerInch')                    % gives 96
```

Funny thing is that to get the save image size I had to put 70 dpi (Win7 + R2001b), which is different from the screen DPI resolution (96 dpi) MATLAB stores in root object (see `get(0)`)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these options actually do quite what the answer requests, which is to emulate the Save As menu output size.  The `getframe` command will get you the data you need to use `imwrite` and get the requested (true-to-screen) output size.  I have detailed the process in my answer.

Comment: @chappjc Agree. But this was not clear for me from the question. Interestingly, the 1201/561 is nearly the same as 901/420. This might be solved with proper DPI value

Comment: [Here's an old post from a MathWorks employee](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/74104#188292) trying to explain how MATLAB gets the resolution used to print.  It's old and vague, but the point is that it seems to be system-dependent, so trying guessing the number might be a waste of time.  Why `get(0,'ScreenPixelsPerInch')` gives a different number I don't know.  But you can at least `set(0,'ScreenPixelsPerInch',R)`.  This is why I suggested `getframe` to handle it for you.

Comment: On my machine with a 1600x1200 monitor, I couldn't find a suitable `-r`.  The closes to the Save As output was with `-r87`. Nothing gave an exact match to the screen grab saved by `getframe`.

Answer (score 1):

You request having code that saves a file with the same dimensions as that saved via the manual "Save As" menu.  To get the same size as with the "Save As" menu, you have to use the `getframe` and `frame2im` commands as follows,

```
F = getframe(gcf);
[im,map] = frame2im(F);
if isempty(map)
    imwrite(im,'SaveAsFig.jpg');
else
    imwrite(im,map,'SaveAsFig.jpg');
end
```

If you use `saveas` or `print`, you will likely get a file with different dimensions. Similarly for just `imwrite(fftout2)`, which stores a file that will have the native matrix size rather than the "Save As" size.
The operation of `getframe` ensures the file resolution reflects what you have on screen.  From the documentation:

> Resolution of Captured Frames
>
> The resolution of the framed image depends on the size of the axes in pixels when `getframe` is called. As the `getframe` command takes a snapshot of the screen, if the axes is small in size (e.g.,because you have restricted the view to a window within the axes), `getframe` captures fewer screen pixels, and the captured image might have poor resolution if enlarged for display.

**EDIT:**

**To get the same effect with the `print` command** you need to specify screen resolution with the `-r` switch as described in [this MathWorks guide to figure settings](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/changing-a-figures-settings.html?s_tid=doc_12b#f3-99727).  The `-r0` switch gives you the default resolution, but not necessarily the resolution Save As gives you.  For example:

```
print -djpeg -r0 'FIG1.jpg'
```

The resolution used by Save As and `getframe`/`frame2im` differ from the automatic resolution used here.  Interestingly, I tried to find a `-r` that gave the me same resolution returned by the Save As menu (and `getframe`), but was unable to find a suitable `-r`.  The closes was `-r87` for my 1600x1200 monitor. Nothing gave an exact match to the screen grab saved by `getframe`. Perhaps its best just to use `getframe` if you just want to get what is on the screen without worrying about print resolution.  [DPI is kind of a silly concept anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19310540/2778484) unless you are printing or always expecting to display the file on a monitor of the same size.